# Finding the line tangent to $\mathrm{e}^x$

Tags: calculus

The question states find the tangent line to $y = e^x$ that goes through the point $(0,0)$.

To help myself I also graphed the function on [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3De%5Ex).

I got as far as :

$y = mx + c$

$c$ is the $y$-intercept which is zero thus

$y = mx$

Substituting $y$ with the function:

$e^x = mx$

If I continue with this will I get to the answer?

Comment: Tangent to the curve at which point??

Comment: @SchrodingersCat : That is, in fact, what the problem implicitly requires the solver to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first we can think about the general tangent to a $y=e^x$ curve.

For this we need to know the point on the curve at which we draw the tangent and the gradient of the line at that point (the derivative).

Let the point at which we draw the tangent be $(x_0, y_0)$.

Now as the curve is $y=e^x$, we know that $y_0=e^{x_0}$.

So the point on the curve is $(x_0, e^{x_0})$

Now we find the gradient, $m$, of the tangent to $y=e^x$ at the point on the curve. This we get by differentiation:

$$m=\frac{dy}{dx}\vert_{x_0}=e^x\vert_{x_0}=e^{x_0}$$

Now we use the fact that the line through a point $(x_0, y_0)$ with gradient $m$ is given by:

$$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$

In our case:
$$y-e^{x_0}=e^{x_0}(x-x_0)$$

Now we know the line passes through $(0,0)$, so:

$$0-e^{x_0}=e^{x_0}(0-x_0)$$
$$e^{x_0}=x_0e^{x_0}$$
$$\therefore x_0=\frac{e^{x_0}}{e^{x_0}}=1$$

So now you just substitute that back into the general equation to get the equation of the line passing through your point.

$$y-e^1=e^1(x-1)$$
$$y=ex$$

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line to your curve in $(a,e^a)$ is $y_a(x)=e^ax+c$. We need to evaluate the constant $c$ : $e^a=y_a(a)=e^a+c \Rightarrow c=e^a(1-a)$.
So $y_a(x)=e^a(x+1-a)$. You want to find an $a$ such $y_a$ goes through $(0,0)$, so you need an $a$ such a $y_a(0)=0 \iff e^a(1-a)=0 \iff a=1 $.

So the tangent line that goes through $(0,0)$ is $y_1(x)=ex$, the tangent to the curve in $(1,e)$.